# Running Commands in Python

Tags: python, command

I am new to python. Any ideas why this does not work:

```
C:\Python27>python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> cmdBuilder = os.path.join("C:\\","Program Files","InstallShield","2011 SAB",
"System","IsCmdBld.exe")
>>> os.system(cmdBuilder)
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
1
>>>
```

The executable does actually exist. It seems to be getting caught up on the space between Program and Files

Thanks

Comment: Try "progra~1" instead of "Program Files".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping the executable in quotes:

```
>>> os.system('"'+cmdBuilder+'"')
```

Answer (score 1):

Because parts of the path contain whitespaces.

See also

http://help.wugnet.com/windows2/Program-space-batch-file-ftopict489742.html